# UPDATE table using PDO using a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to be able to put a column name as a arg and then the new info to go into the the column as arg2. Can I have some help? Thanks.

```
public function update($info, $new_info){
        try{
            $con=$this->connection;
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql='UPDATE users SET $info=:info WHERE username=:username';

            $prepare=$con->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR=>PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
            $prepare->execute(array(':info'=> $new_info, ':username'=>$this->username));
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo '<br/><b>Error:</b> ', $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks good to me, what's the problem?

Comment: When I run it, it says: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: I don't know how to set the column name without it being a variable. I also tried setting it as :column, then assigning it the variable. Nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using single quote:

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET $info=:info WHERE username=:username";
```